# Wordpress child theme translation

Tags: wordpress, themes, translation

I'd like to translate a child theme of wordpress twentythirteen theme.
Following the documentation, I've created and located fr_FR.po and fr_FR.mo files in a languages subdirectory of the child theme. The translation files contain only the child theme's specific translations. Then I've added the following in functions.php:

```
function theme_vja_setup() {      
  load_child_theme_textdomain('twentythirteen', 
       get_stylesheet_directory()."/languages");
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','theme_vja_setup');
```

I can't get what I'm doing wrong but I can't get the child theme translated

Looking at wordpress trac:

load_child_theme _text_domain verifies that $path is not empty and then call load_theme_text_domain.
load_theme_text_domain in turn tries to load the parent localization file wp-content/languages/themes/twentythirteen-fr_FR.mo which exists --> the function load_text_domain returns true and the loading stops

Any direction would be appreciated, I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need this code in functions.php. Copy the .po and .mo files in the wp-content/languages/themes folder.

Name them:

```
[yourchildthemename]-fr_FR.po
```

and

```
[yourchildthemename]-fr_FR.mo.
```

(replace [yourchildthemename] by the slug of your child theme)

Regards Tom

Comment: So what is the real purpose of load_child_theme_textdomain function versus load_theme_textdomain called with the childthemename as text domain?

Comment: I don`t know, I never tested these functions. I always do it like this because it is simple.